# TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined at Class.setup (http://192.168.1.206:8069/web/static/src/js/views/view_dialogs.js:376:45)

Tags: javascript, odoo-12, odoo-13, odoo-14

I have this custom widget which functions as the following, when clicking on the "search more" in a One2many it is supposed to expand a wizard displaying the Treeview of products
Current situation is that it stopped working so I tried debugging with assets and when I click on the "Search more" hyperlink I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined
    at Class.setup (http://192.168.1.206:8069/web/static/src/js/views/view_dialogs.js:376:45)
when clicking on the view_dialogs.js
```

when i click on the link in the error it jumps to this line

```
var view = new ViewClass(fieldsViews[this.viewType], _.extend(viewOptions, {
```

[image]

Comment: What values does your `fieldsViews`, `this.viewType` and `viewOptions` has? Maybe something is undefined?

Comment: What's on the line 376 of `view_dialogs.js` ?